# assigning random number to an item and depending on that number the resultant number we get is store in some other variable

Tags: matlab

please could you help me to sort out one problem in matlab.

I have got a product  i.e 100 items and i want to assign a random numbers between 1 and 3 to this item.  depending on the number which i will get after assigning a random number to that item,i have to arrange the obtained number in some sort of array or another variable .

I try like this

```
item=1:100
R=randint(3,1,1)
```

shall i use some array or `for` loop so that i can solve this problem in matlab.

thanks

Comment: This is very unclear. What does "i have to arrange the obtained number in some sort of array or other variable" mean?

Comment: Item no Random no
1 -------
2 -------.
3 -------
. .
. .
. .
100 .

this is the rough idea the first column is item no the second is random value . now I should be able to check let suppose item 1 has random value let suppose 2 and so fourth. how shall I know which item have which random value. probably loops .......thanks for comment  I think its now much clearer.

Comment: Are you looking for `R=randi(3,100,1);`? Then `R(47)` would give you the random value for item 47.

Comment: not exactly. Randi(3,1,1) this function generate three value 1 or 2 or 3 these random value will be assign to item no. as it is randomly generated we don't know which item no will assign which value. we need some mechanism so that we know that let suppose item no 4 has random value 1, item 50 has random value suppose 2 etc I think we need for loop etc  thanks

Comment: That's not what I said. Try executing the code I put in my comment and look at the resulting array. It should give you 100 random values between 1 and 3.

Comment: Using the code I gave, you find the random value assigned to item 4 by using `R(4)`. You find the value assigned to item 50 using `R(50)`. If this is not what you want, please clarify.

Comment: Does that work, or were you looking for something else?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand you rightly, but I've reproduced your case like this:

```
s.item   = 1:100;
s.range  = randi(3, size(s.item));
s.number = arrayfun(@(x) randi(x, 1, 1), s.range);
```

Where, `s.item` is label of your item but you may not need this. I produce the range of random number and store it in `s.range`. Then I generate random value depending on range and store it in `s.number`. This may be an alternative to loops.

I hope this would be helpful for your case..

Comment: i m not interesting to generate just random number, but the range of random number which will be given to itmes and we will get another number or variable. i dont think it could be solve without an array or loop. thanks

Comment: @nissoo - I see.. You should add this to your question post and provide an example would be greate,  it is not so clear now.. Thanks. And you are right loop is necessary.